# Script execute fail with the imported function

Tags: bash

I have four files in my `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
handle_attack.sh  notify_about_attack.sh  stae_baned_ip.exp  stae.conf
```

The `notify_about_attack.sh` will execute:

[image]

You see the snapshot, the red arrow is the issue place, it did not execute success, in the `ban_ip()` method, even did not execute `echo "加入stae.conf函数之前" >> /tmp/ban.log`.

code is bellow:

```
    ...
    echo "FastNetMon Guard: IP $1 blocked because $2 attack with power $3 pps" >> /tmp/ban.log
    source ./handle_attack.sh
    echo "加载handle_attack.sh成功" >> /tmp/ban.log
    ban_ip $1 $2 $3
    # You can add ban code here!
    exit 0
```

The `handle_attack.sh` code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function ban_ip(){

        echo "加入stae.conf函数之前" >> /tmp/ban.log
        source ./stae.conf
        echo "加入了stae.conf到函数" >> /tmp/ban.log
        expect /usr/local/bin/stae_baned_ip.exp $USER $HOST $PASSWORD $TIMEOUT $baned_ip

        cur_date=$(date "+%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        echo "当前时间:$cur_date" >> /tmp/ban.log
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                # 追加到文件
                echo "[禁止成功] 攻击方向:$2 pps:$3  被攻击者:$1  时间:$cur_date" >> stae_record.log

        else
                # 追加到文件
                echo "[禁止失败] 攻击方向:$2 pps:$3  被攻击者:$1  时间:$cur_date" >> stae_record.log
        fi
        exit 0
}
```

The `stae_baned_ip.exp` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set user     [lindex $argv 0]
set host     [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set timeout  [lindex $argv 3]
set baned_ip [lindex $argv 4]

echo "${user}  ${host}  ${password}  ${timeout}  ${baned_ip}" >> /tmp/ban.log

spawn ssh $host -l $user

expect {
        "(yes/no)?" {
                send "yes\n"
                expect "password:"
                send "$password\n"
        }
        "password:" {
                send "$password\n"
        }
}

expect "#"
# 下面检测是否登录到host
#send "uname\n"
#expect "Linux"

send "IP route-stae ${baned_ip} 255.255.255.255 null tag666\n"

exit 0
```

And the `stae.conf`:

```
USER="root"
HOST="201.48.116.74"
PASSWORD="asdasd!"
TIMEOUT=60
```

Comment: How do you run `notify_about_attack.sh`? Try to run it with `bash -x notify_about_attack.sh`, or set the x option in the script with `set -x`, to print the commands and their arguments as they are executed. It will help you understand why it fails.

Comment: its a fastnetmon file. i use iperf to ddos attack it can be execute.

Comment: Also your `ban_ip` function uses `exit 0` at the end, that will exit the entire script, not just the function.

Comment: @Pawamoy ok but why the ban_ip method do not execute?

Comment: That is the question. Add `set -x` at the beginning of your script to see what happens when you execute it.

Comment: @Pawamoy ok. i will do that when i arrive home.

Comment: As a side note, the 'if' in your ban_ip function will always be true and the else part will never be executed. $? has the return code of the previous echo and if it has errored then you have much bigger problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using FastNetMon! Could you also share content of FastNetMon's log file /var/log/fastnetmon.log? Usually, FastNetMon writes log messages about any issues with notify script.

One of the common issues that you *should* read stdin content in your script. You could read it and discard this way:
cat > /dev/null

Comment: last night i have solved the issue. i will post the solution after i arrive company. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I get wrong of my import way:

```
source ./handle_attack.sh
```

I use `.` it works:

```
. /usr/local/bin/handle_attack.sh
```

And I also deleted the redundant `exit 0` in `ban_ip` method.